# How can i count values per hour and display the previous and the next hour to the one with the highest values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This a small sample of my data, which is in contained in a bigger pandas df:

```
    Year    Month   Day Hour    errors
0   2018    10      15  23      149
1   2016    9       21  14      114
2   2018    10      14  23      106
3   2016    5       19  14      100
4   2018    10      19  9       85
5   2017    6       15  10      79
6   2017    6       15  13      76
7   2017    6       15  9       71
8   2016    9       21  15      70
9   2016    9       13  14      65
10  2018    10      14  22      64
11  2019    3       27  16      62
12  2018    10      16  0       60
13  2016    5       19  15      59
14  2018    5       30  9       58
15  2017    6       15  12      52
16  2018    6       15  14      51
17  2016    9       19  16      51
18  2016    9       20  13      51
19  2016    9       21  16      48
20  2018    10      22  12      48
```

This data shows the number of errors by year month day and hour. I know how to find the biggest number of errors per hour and sort it, that's not the problem. What i need to do is to display the hours (with their respective month, year and day) with the highest number of errors, but also display the precedent hour, and the next hour to that one with the highest number of errors. I also need to present this table in descending order.

This is an example of my desired output but the data is not real, i'm faking it because i don't know the true values of the data, but it's useful to provide an ilustrated example:

```
    Year    Month   Day Hour    errors
0   2018    10      15  21      120 # Previous hour
1   2018    10      15  22      150 # Hour of the same year, month and day with the biggest number of errors
2   2018    10      15  23      130 # Next hour
3   2016    7       29  16      40  # Previous hour
4   2016    7       29  17      90  # Hour of the same year, month and day with the biggest number of errors
5   2016    7       29  18      20  # Next hour
```

And so on with the rest of the data. The idea is simple, but i can't figure out how to organize the rows in the dataframe to be displayed this way. Can someone help me with this please?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Do you have several rows for a given `Year` + `Month` + `Day` + `Hours` ?

Comment: yes i do, In fact the data is structured in such a way that it counts the number of errors per hour, so in the same year, month and day every hour is displayed along with the number of errors

Comment: How do you know what are the *next* and the *previous* hours ?

Comment: Because as i said before, every hour of the day is displayed by year, month and day, so all the hours are in the `hour` column. To know which is the precedent hour and the next hour, you should watch that their respective year and month  matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we have the following test data:

```
   Year  Month  Day  Hour  errors
0  2016      5   19    14      51
1  2016      5   19    15      52
2  2016      5   19    16     100
3  2016      5   19    17      54
4  2016      5   19    18      55
5  2016      5   20     8      41
6  2016      5   20     9      42
7  2016      5   20    10     200
8  2016      5   20    11      43
9  2016      5   20    12      44
```

We append an auxiliary column `maxerr` marking the rows with the maximum errors per day with a 1:

```
df['maxerr'] = None
df.iloc[df.groupby(['Year', 'Month', 'Day']).errors.idxmax().values,-1] = 1
```

Then we propagate this marker one row up and down:

```
df['maxerr'] = df['maxerr'].ffill(limit=1).bfill(limit=1)
```

After dropping all remaining (unmarked) rows and our auxiliary column

```
df.dropna().drop(columns='maxerr')
```

we get:

```
   Year  Month  Day  Hour  errors
1  2016      5   19    15      52
2  2016      5   19    16     100
3  2016      5   19    17      54
6  2016      5   20     9      42
7  2016      5   20    10     200
8  2016      5   20    11      43
```

(If the original data shouldn't be sorted by time, we'll have to sort them first by `df = df.sort_values(['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour'])`)

**UPDATE based on additional requirements given in comment below:**
In order to only include hours *directly adjacent* to the maximum error hours, we temporarily create a datetime index and upsample it to hours. After upsampling the dataframe we discard this index and we continue as previously. The only differene is that due to the inserted NaNs all columns got converted to float, which we undo by `astype(int)`.

```
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour']]))
df = df.resample('1H').asfreq()
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df['maxerr'] = None
df.iloc[df.groupby(['Year', 'Month', 'Day']).errors.idxmax().values,-1] = 1
df['maxerr'] = df['maxerr'].ffill(limit=1).bfill(limit=1)
df = df.dropna().drop(columns='maxerr').astype(int)
```

With these test data:

```
    Year  Month  Day  Hour  errors
0   2016      5   19    14      51
1   2016      5   19    15      52
2   2016      5   19    16     100
3   2016      5   19    17      54
4   2016      5   19    18      55
5   2016      5   20     8      41
6   2016      5   20     9      42
7   2016      5   20    10     200
8   2016      5   20    12      44
9   2016      5   20    23      45
10  2016      5   21     0     300
11  2016      5   21     1      46
```

we get:

```
    Year  Month  Day  Hour  errors
1   2016      5   19    15      52
2   2016      5   19    16     100
3   2016      5   19    17      54
19  2016      5   20     9      42
20  2016      5   20    10     200
33  2016      5   20    23      45
34  2016      5   21     0     300
35  2016      5   21     1      46
```

We see that row 8 is not included as its hour 12 is not directly following hour 10 in the maximum row 7. Further, row 9 from the previous day is included for the maximum at 0 hours in row 10.

**2nd UPDATE based on additional requirements given in comment below:** In order to include maximum error rows along with prev and next rows only if both prev and next exist, and not include anything if either prev or next are missing, we insert in the code of the 1st update the following line *before* the `ffill` / `bfill` line:

```
df['maxerr'] = df.maxerr + df.errors.shift(-1) + df.errors.shift(1)
```

If prev (`shift(1)`) or next (`shift(-1`)) are missing, they propagate `NaN` to maxerr. After filling and dropping `NaN`s as previously we get in our example:

```
    Year  Month  Day  Hour  errors
1   2016      5   19    15      52
2   2016      5   19    16     100
3   2016      5   19    17      54
33  2016      5   20    23      45
34  2016      5   21     0     300
35  2016      5   21     1      46
```

Here, the maximum errors row at 10 hrs is excluded along with its previous row at 9 hours because there's no row for 11 hrs (day = 20).

Comment: Hi @Stef!! Thank you very much for your answer and your time. Your solution seems simple and truely effective. I like it!! You also provided a good explanation. Thanks again!! :)

Comment: Hi Stef, your code works in a similar way to Code Different's code. You are taking the previous and next hours from different days but the hours that should be considered as next and previous ones are the hours of the same day, if there were no consecutive previous and next hours in the same day, then you discard these and continue to the next day. It's better explained in my answer to Code Different. Could you help me with this please? Thank you very much again

Comment: Like if we have the max at 7 hrs and there is no row for 6 hrs (or 8 hrs) then we don't include **any** row of this day in the result? The same if the max occurs at 0 hrs or 23 hrs where can't be a previous or next hour respectively? Maybe its easier you prepare a sample with desired output where all these special cases occur.

Comment: If we have the max at 7 and there's no row for 6 and 8 we only include the max at 7 and no previous or next row for that result, only the max. In the other hand if you have a max at 23h you should consider the midnight of the next day ss the following hour amd viceversa if the max was at midnight of a given day, you should consider the 23h of the previous day as the previous hour. The thing is, the hours need to be consecutive

Comment: again, 1000 times thank you   This is pretty much what i wanted. Just one more question please and i'll leave you alone, how could i not include none of the hours that are not consecutive? I mean, instead of including all the `maxerr` hours even if they don't have any prior or next consecutive hours, how could i include `maxerr` hours that have prior or next consecutive hours only? Again, thank you very much

Comment: Sorry, your comment was incomplete, what did you say?

Comment: OK, I carefully re-read you comment: so you want to include max along with prev and next only if both prev and next exist and not include anything if either prev or next are missing - right?

Comment: Yes that's it, what i asked you before in my previous comments was also ok, don't worry about that, it's just that i need both use cases, your updated answer was ok. Now what i need is the other use case, it's exactly what you said in your very last comment. Including max along with prev and next only if both prev and next exist, and not include anything if either prev or next are missing. This is, filter out any hour non consecutive prev and next hours. I apologize if i'm not being clear. I know this is a tricky problem, but really you don't know how much you help me here. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Hi @Stef!! That did the job just nice!! Thank you for providing a great support with this problem and for the great and clarifying explanations about how the code works !! You really helped me here and i really want to thank you again!! 

Answer (score 1):

`idxmax` is your friend. Since you consider only consecutive hours for "previous" and "next", you need to resample your data.

First, construct a data frame from your sample data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

string = """
Year    Month   Day Hour    errors
2018    10      15  23      149
2016    9       21  14      114
2018    10      14  23      106
2016    5       19  14      100
2018    10      19  9       85
2017    6       15  10      79
2017    6       15  13      76
2017    6       15  9       71
2016    9       21  15      70
2016    9       13  14      65
2018    10      14  22      64
2019    3       27  16      62
2018    10      16  0       60
2016    5       19  15      59
2018    5       30  9       58
2017    6       15  12      52
2018    6       15  14      51
2016    9       19  16      51
2016    9       20  13      51
2016    9       21  16      48
2018    10      22  12      48
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(string), sep='\\s+')
```

Next, resample your data to hourly. The missing hours are filled with `NaN`:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour']])
df = df.set_index('Timestamp').resample('H').asfreq()
```

Find the indexes of the row that has the max errors per day:

```
idxmax = df.groupby(['Year', 'Month', 'Day'])['errors'].idxmax()
```

And finally the errors of the previous and the next hour:

```
result = df.loc[idxmax] \
        .join(df['errors'].shift(1), rsuffix='_prev') \
        .join(df['errors'].shift(-1), rsuffix='_next')
```

Result:

```
Year  Month  Day  Hour  errors  errors_prev  errors_next
2016      5   19    14     100          NaN         59.0
2016      9   13    14      65         59.0         51.0
2016      9   19    16      51         65.0         51.0
2016      9   20    13      51         51.0        114.0
2016      9   21    14     114         51.0         70.0
2017      6   15    10      79         71.0         52.0
2018      5   30     9      58         76.0         51.0
2018      6   15    14      51         58.0         64.0
2018     10   14    23     106         64.0        149.0
2018     10   15    23     149        106.0         60.0
2018     10   16     0      60        149.0         85.0
2018     10   19     9      85         60.0         48.0
2018     10   22    12      48         85.0         62.0
2019      3   27    16      62         48.0          NaN
```

---

If you want to get a data frame by the shape you specified:

```
result2 = result.set_index(['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour']) \
                .stack() \
                .reset_index()

result2.columns = ['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Type', 'errors']
```

Output:

```
Year  Month  Day  Hour         Type  errors
2016      5   19    14       errors   100.0
2016      5   19    14  errors_next    59.0
2016      9   13    14       errors    65.0
2016      9   13    14  errors_prev    59.0
2016      9   13    14  errors_next    51.0
2016      9   19    16       errors    51.0
2016      9   19    16  errors_prev    65.0
2016      9   19    16  errors_next    51.0
2016      9   20    13       errors    51.0
2016      9   20    13  errors_prev    51.0
2016      9   20    13  errors_next   114.0
2016      9   21    14       errors   114.0
2016      9   21    14  errors_prev    51.0
2016      9   21    14  errors_next    70.0
2017      6   15    10       errors    79.0
2017      6   15    10  errors_prev    71.0
2017      6   15    10  errors_next    52.0
2018      5   30     9       errors    58.0
2018      5   30     9  errors_prev    76.0
2018      5   30     9  errors_next    51.0
2018      6   15    14       errors    51.0
2018      6   15    14  errors_prev    58.0
2018      6   15    14  errors_next    64.0
2018     10   14    23       errors   106.0
2018     10   14    23  errors_prev    64.0
2018     10   14    23  errors_next   149.0
2018     10   15    23       errors   149.0
2018     10   15    23  errors_prev   106.0
2018     10   15    23  errors_next    60.0
2018     10   16     0       errors    60.0
2018     10   16     0  errors_prev   149.0
2018     10   16     0  errors_next    85.0
2018     10   19     9       errors    85.0
2018     10   19     9  errors_prev    60.0
2018     10   19     9  errors_next    48.0
2018     10   22    12       errors    48.0
2018     10   22    12  errors_prev    85.0
2018     10   22    12  errors_next    62.0
2019      3   27    16       errors    62.0
2019      3   27    16  errors_prev    48.0
```

Comment: wow!! @Code DIfferent to say that i'm astonished wouldn't be enough. I'm pretty sure that i couldn't have come with a solution like this in a 100 years. Thank you very much for yout help and for teaching me this lesson. I will spend some time breaking this by pieces and seeing what it does.

I just have one more question and i would like to clarify a thing. The next and previous hours means that the hours must be consecutive, if there's a gap, then they need to be filtered out from the final result. How would you do it in this case please?

Thanks again!!

Comment: I see that you are counting as the previous and next hours, hours that are in previous and next days, but this is not how it needs to be done. I just want to include the previous and next hours in the same date. This means that if in a certain date i have one hour, let's say 7 a.m. which number of errors is the maximum of that date, let's say 150, i need to now how many errors there were at 6 a.m. and at 8 a.m. but only for that same day, not the previous or the next days, only for that very same days.

Comment: If there is a gap in the next nd previous hours are not consecutive, then, this hours are filtered out and not included in the final result.

I'm sorry if i bother you with this, i know it's a bit tricky to get it, but i really thank you very much for your time and help :)

Comment: Ah the devil is in the detail as I expected. One more question before I edit the answer: if the hour with the max errors is 23:00, does the midnight of the following day count as "the next hour"?

Comment: yes it does. You may consider the midnight of the following day as the next hour and the same for the previous hour if that was the case. As you said yes, the details are the tricky part of this problem :/